# Firebase Dynamic Links - huge delay in clicks being tracked in my Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-dynamic-links, click-tracking

I have created a few Firebase Dynamic Links yet unlike Google URL Shortener the click-tracking is no longer instant.

I have some links created over 18 hours again that have been visited lots of time (by myself) however these clicks have yet to be registered in the Firebase Console - there is obviously a large delay but I cannot understand why this would be nor do I know when I can expect to see the clicks appear in my console - any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find out what caused this or if this can me remedied?

Comment: @Sebastian no I didn't unfortunately